# How to solve an equation with the sum of minima numerically?

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, matlab

The equation is given by

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \min(\gamma, \beta a_n)=N$$
where $\beta$ is the variable with $\beta\in[0,\sqrt\gamma/\min(a_n\mid a_n>0)]$, $ \gamma   $ is a constant with $1\le\gamma\le N$, and $a_n$ is an nonnegative constant.

I know that the function $f(\beta)=\sum_{n=1}^N \min(\gamma, \beta a_n)-N$ is strictly increasing. Also, $f(0)<0 $ and $ f(\sqrt\gamma/\min(a_n\mid a_n > 0 )) > 0$. Thus, there must exist an unique solution for the above equation. How can I find the solution numerically? e.g. using matlab. Increasing $ \beta$ slowly works, but it is not accurate.

Comment: have you tried with bi-section algorithm ?

Comment: useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: I don't understand why is there $\sqrt{\gamma}$ in the upper bound. $\frac{1}{\min a_n}$ should work as well.

Comment: @uranix I got this equation from an optimization problem. Yes, without  $\sqrt\gamma$ is ok of course. Sorry for not simplifying the equation.

Comment: @Cardinal : Yes, I think bi-section is a good choice now. It is simple and relatively efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest generic (read: linear convergence) algorithm given a continuous function and an interval $[a,b]$ with $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$ is called bisection (sometimes binary search):

1. Look at the sign $s$ of $f(\frac{a+b}2)$

   - If $s = 0$, we are done with the exact solution $\frac{a+b}2$.
   - If $s = 1$, we know the root is in $[a, \frac{a+b}2]$, so set $b = \frac{a+b}2$ and repeat until the interval length $b-a$ is less than $2\epsilon$
   - If $s = -1$, we know the root is in $[\frac{a+b}2, b]$, so set $a=\frac{a+b}2$ and repeat until the interval length $b-a$ is less than $2\epsilon$
2. If $b-a<2\epsilon$, return $\frac{a+b}2$. We know that the actual root is wihin $\epsilon$ of this value.

The guaranteed accuracy ($\frac{b-a}2$) is halved in each iteration, so we converge linearly to the solution. In other words we need linear time if the accuracy is given in digits. This algorithm is optimal and always converges as long as $f$ is continuous.

A slight modification to prevent numerical problems if a root is on an interval boundary (i.e. found exactly), but the value returned isn't exactly $0$ would be to also return if $|f(\frac{a+b}2)| < \delta$ for some tolerance $\delta > 0$.

Comment: That's not an exponential convergence. It's a linear convergence (slowest). I.e.
$$
\epsilon_{k+1} \leq 0.5 \epsilon_k.
$$
Quadratic convergence can be achieved by Newton's method, and that would be
$$
\epsilon_{k+1} \leq C \epsilon_k^2.
$$
Exponential convergence is convergence for every $p$
$$
\epsilon_{k+1} \leq C_p \epsilon^p, \quad \forall p \exists C_p
$$
and I don't know such iterative methods.

Comment: @uranix How is that slow convergence? Also AFAIK the convergence is measured globally as $$\epsilon \le 2^{-k} |x - x_0|\le 2^{-k-1} (b-a)$$ Newton also only converges quadratically if the function is at least $C^1$, wich this one is not.

Comment: What you wrote is called linear convergence. For iterative methods, linear convergence is not the same that linear convergence for ODE, for example. Newton method I've gave only as an example of method with quadratic convergence. Actually there's no need in iterative method for this problem, you might look at my answer, no tolerance $\delta$ at all.

Comment: @uranix I did. Good catch for that. (+1 btw) I'll leave this inaccuracy for the moment as I don't have time now.

Comment: @uranix Fixed it now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is piecewise linear. I suggest finding all the points where it's slope changes, seem to be $\beta_n = \frac{\gamma}{a_n}$ (If some $a_n$ are zero, simply kick them out of sum), sort them by value and find the interval $[\beta_k, \beta_{k+1}]$ where the root is (binary search, $O(\log n)$ complexity). On that interval, the root can be found by solving a linear equation.

Here's MATLAB code for that

```
N = 20;
gamma = 3;
a = .1 + 3 * rand(N, 1);

mina = min(a);

x = linspace(0, gamma / mina, 1000);

f = @(beta) sum(min(gamma, a * beta(:)')) - N;

corners = gamma ./ a;
corners = [corners; 0; gamma / mina];
values = f(corners);
[values, reorder] = sort(values);
corners = corners(reorder);

low = 1;
upp = length(corners);

iters = 0;
while upp - low > 1
    iters = iters + 1;
    mid = floor((upp + low) / 2 + 0.1);
    % low < mid < upp
    if values(mid) > N
        upp = mid;
    else
        low = mid;
    end
end

fprintf('Binary search in %d iters, N at [%f, %f]\n', ...
    iters, corners(low), corners(upp));

root = corners(low) + ...
    (corners(upp) - corners(low)) / (values(upp) - values(low)) * ...
    (N - values(low));

fprintf('The root is %f\n', root);

plot(x, f(x), '-', corners, values, 'r.', ...
    x, N, 'k-', [root], [N], 'g*');
```

[image]